# How to get reels views in facebook page using FB graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook graph API to get the our page video views () like this.

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/$pageid/insights?metric=page_video_views&since=from-date&until=to-date&period=day&access_token=page_access_token

Above API result provides full video views,reels views are not included.

My requirement is there any way to get views on reels? or breakdown views into reels views and full video views.

Comment: You can use Video Insights Reels Metrics API:- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights#reels-metrics

Comment: @ArpitJain Mentioned Video Insights Reels Metrics API is video level data, I want page level reel data.

Comment: Meta Graph Page Insights API says- Interactions on Reels are not included.

Comment: Please check the limitation section of the Page Insignt API:- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v17.0/insights#limitations